# Can't launch receiver application anymore

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I am having some issues with chromecast and launching my receiver. It was working fine before and now it is failing to connect every time.

I have solved the issue before by removing all running google play services and then rebooting my device but I would like to know why this is happening. Can anyone help me understand this a little better?

My code to connect to a device has not changed at all but it has just stopped working. Seems like it is some sort of leaked resource maybe. . .

I attempt to launch this code in the onConnected Method of the GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks()

```
  // Launch the Receiver Application
    Cast.CastApi.launchApplication(mGoogleApiClient, mStrGoogleCastReceiverId, false)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Cast.ApplicationConnectionResult>() 
                {
                 @Override
                public void onResult(Cast.ApplicationConnectionResult result) 
                    {
                    // Get the Status of the connection
                    Status status = result.getStatus();

                       if(status.isSuccess()){
                        // i am not longer hitting this code because device fails to have successful status
                       }
                    }
               });
```

Comment: The code snippet you have is about launching your receiver app and not connecting to your chromecast so please clarify which one is the issue, connecting to the device or launching your app?

Comment: right, sorry @AliNaddaf i am having trouble launching the application updated above

Comment: @AliNaddaf rebooting the chromecast fixed the issue, but why is this happening?

Comment: Hard to say, without having logs .... If it happens again, connect to your chromecast on port 9222 using chrome debugger and turn logging on and see what it says and include that info in your post.

Comment: @AliNaddaf see update above, about additional error. why is this happening on some devices 2.3 Android

Comment: The new log snippet is related to connectivity and not launching receiver so you keep switching between two different topics. If you have an issue with connection, please open a new post otherwise it will be confusing for folks and anyone who wants to comment on this.

Comment: @AliNaddaf removed i will open new topic. But how do i get to chromecast via ip and port to use debugger?

Comment: Go to https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver and search for "Debugging"